# Android jSoup Help

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse html from this url http://skyalipi.blogspot.com/2011/04/there-is-no-resistance-without.html using jSoup. I am using this code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("http://skyalipi.blogspot.com/2011/04/there-is-no-resistance-without.html");  

       Log.d("test", "the elements"+doc);
```

In the log, I am getting the following

```
05-26 12:05:05.355: DEBUG/test(696): the elements<html>
05-26 12:05:05.355: DEBUG/test(696):  <head></head>
05-26 12:05:05.355: DEBUG/test(696):  <body>
05-26 12:05:05.355: DEBUG/test(696):   http://skyalipi.blogspot.com/2011/04/there-is-no-resistance-without.html 
05-26 12:05:05.355: DEBUG/test(696):  </body>
05-26 12:05:05.355: DEBUG/test(696): </html>
```

I Want to get the paragraph contents. I dont know where I am going wrong. I refered to the following url too http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup is treating your URL as if it is the text that you want to parse, and is converting it into valid HTML so that it can be parsed.  I think you want to connect to the site and retrieve the content at that url, then parse the result:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://skyalipi.blogspot.com/2011/04/there-is-no-resistance-without.html").get();
```

**EDIT**

Have a look at [the documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation) for examples.  You can do things like:

```
Element example = doc.getElementById("alternatives1");
Log.d("test","example "+example.text());
```

Comment: @dave.c   Thanks for the quick replyYes I tried connect too. Can U tel me what will be the content of doc after the above statement and how to extract the tags from there. Please help

Comment: @Droidme added a link and a small example

Comment: @dave.c I tried it. but I get the following error

05-26 13:04:42.615: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(994): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-26 13:04:42.615: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(994):     at slots.jsoup.soup.onCreate(soup.java:33)

Comment: @dave.c  The 33 line is Element example = doc.getElementById("alternatives1"); Please help

Comment: @Droidme Then `doc` is null.  Are you actually calling `get()`?  Do you have internet permissions?

Comment: @dave.c Thanks I had not set them :). Thanks for the help.  I want to get all the paragraphs of the link. Can I use getallElements?